# RecyclerView or ViewPager or ViewFlipper

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm little confused after observing the play store app;Wondering the play store uses recyclerview or ViewPager or ViewFlipper to list offer.Please check the attached images rounded in blue color

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Actually he is using both  `RecyclerView` and `ViewPager`

for the purpose of advertising above like in image he is using ViewPager with AutoScroll and for the App View in Horizontal Scrolling he is using RecyclerView with orientation Horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

**#.** This behavior can be done by using `RecyclerView` with `LinearLayoutManager`.

**#.** For each item of `RecyclerView`, use `CardView` containing `ViewPager` or `ViewFlipper` to show auto scroll-able multiple ads on each `CardView`.

Comment: can you please post some link to achieve the above @FAT